# How to find C Flags for a package (for example LibXml2) using cmake

Tags: c, cmake

I am trying to add C Flags for a particular package to CMAKE_C_FLAGS. But I do not know how to find the C flags for the package using cmake. Does anybody know how

Answer (score 2):

There is no general way (cross platform) to get the correct cflags for a certain package, for windows for example you have no way to check even if the package is installed at all since there is no default location. In unix systems you can expect to find cflags for a certain package by running

```
pkg-config --cflags packagename
```

Cmake usually has specific scripts to find package and build correct compile flags for them, which fall back to `pkg-config` if it is available and the package has no specific script (for example, if its unknown by Cmake). See

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

for details.

In your case you probably have to supply an ad-hoc recipe for libxml2 package. Other users wrote them and shared, you can find a lot by searching google for "libxml2 cmake". Actually, libxml2 is the one used as example on the same page I linked before on "how to write a custom recipe for a library that is unknown by cmake"